# How do I achieve the full screen swipe/pan back feature for navigation controller?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm implementing a feature in my app that allows user to swipe/pan back to previous controller from anywhere on the screen. But the default swipe/pan back feature provided in navigation controller only works for the screen edge. How can I have it work from anywhere on the screen or how do I achieve something like 'full screen swipe/pan' back feature?

Answer (score 0):

You can add swipe gesture to `view` of viewController like this

```
let recognizer: UISwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.swipeToGoBack))
    recognizer.direction = .right
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)


@objc func swipeToGoBack(_ recognizer:UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
   // add code to dismiss this controller
}
```

Comment: `swipeOpenMenu`? Where was a menu mentioned?